# A possible tag for on-hold questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm relatively new to StackExchange (including this community), but I've noticed in the unanswered questions on this community, there are a **ton** of on-hold questions. I would prefer if it was easier to simply filter out these on-hold questions altogether until they're fixed. It's a lot to wade through, and the questions aren't really answerable as well, they're on-hold.

Is it possible that a tag could be created for questions that are on-hold, to serve as a way to filter them out? It could also help people who want to help others fix their on-hold questions.

Alternatively, is it possible for me to filter out the questions another way?

Comment: Stack Exchange has a really rich search function where you can add a lot of filtering. The query you are looking for is [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20closed%3ano).

Answer (score 5):

Using a tag for this purpose isn't appropriate. It a [meta tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags): a tag which describes something other than the content of the question (examples being a skill level or motivation) or an ill-defined concept. Tags are meant to describe the content of the question, not the current state of a question.

Ideally, it would be nice if the thresholds for questions that appear on the homepage are adjusted to make the homepage more friendly. However, this is something that Stack Exchange staff would need to review. I believe questions are removed from the homepage at a score of -4, regardless of their on-hold status. There may be one or more suggestions on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) regarding this, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: I believe the removal from homepage threshold was changed from -4 to -3 at some point.

Comment: @Ixrec I still still see -3 questions on my homepage. There are some there now.

Comment: "delete everything that's blatantly off-topic as soon as it appears" ([Shog9](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=31225279#31225279))

Comment: @gnat if that's what we're supposed to do why put things on hold?

Comment: @CandiedOrange maybe, because not everything is _blatantly_ off-topic? or maybe, because there are wrong closes?